# How to run one of three different Google Script functions on the same day in a specific order?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have three Google Script functions in a Google Document (we'll call them functionOne, functionTwo and functionThree). What I would like to do is create a new function (we'll call it newFunction) that will run every Friday at 7 am using triggers (this part I know how to do).

What I am having a hard time with is I would like newFunction to call one of functionOne, functionTwo or functionThree in a specific order.

For example, the first Friday, I want functionOne ran, the next Friday functionTwo, the third Friday functionThree and then loop.

How would I be able to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you need something like this

```
function newFunction() {
  var order =
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('order') || '1';
  switch (order) {
    case '1':
      functionOne();
      break;
    case '2':
      functionTwo();
      break;
    case '3':
      functionThree();
      break;
  }
  var nextOrder = '' + (+order < 3 ? +order + 1 : '1');
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('order', nextOrder);
}
```

You can use an external properties store for save the current state of the app. As you can see there is no need to specified a week day.

Comment: Hey contributorpw, thanks for the help. When I put the above code in and try to run the function, it runs without any errors, but it does not do what I would expect it to. functionOne, functionTwo or functionThree does not run.

Comment: @Ryan Sorry this is my fault. It's fixed now. See `var order = ...`